# Color aleatorio del texto en C

Tags: c, color

quiero hacer una función en C que cambie el color del texto entre unos colores definidos con unas constantes lo que quiero hacer es que se escoja un color aleatorio entre las constantes predefinidas e imprima el texto del printf en un color aleatorio.

Dejo el código por aquí.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"
 
int main () {
 
  printf(ANSI_COLOR_RED     "Este texto es de color rojo"     ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n");
 
  return 0;
}
```

El problema es que se como aplicar el color al texto pero no se como hacer que este color sea aleatorio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muy sencillo: creas un *array* de cadenas, y escoges un índice de forma aleatoria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"

static const char *Colores[] = {
    ANSI_COLOR_RED,
    ANSI_COLOR_GREEN,
    ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW,
    ANSI_COLOR_BLUE,
    ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA,
    ANSI_COLOR_CYAN,
    ANSI_COLOR_RESET
};
static const int MAX_COLOR = sizeof( Colores ) / sizeof( Colores[0] );

int main () {
    // Inicializar secuencia aleatoria. ¡ Solo una vez durante todo el programa !
    srand( time( NULL ) );

    printf( "%s%s", Colores[rand( ) % MAX_COLOR], "Este texto es de color aleatorio" );

    return 0;
}
```